# Do empty subdomains hurt a domain's reputation for email deliverability or SEO?

Tags: dns, subdomain

If a company has a lot of old DNS entries for subdomains that point either nowhere (CNAMES that no longer resolve to anywhere) or at servers that are no longer online does that hurt the main domain's reputation for email deliverability or SEO?

I am pushing for a DNS clean up but running up against apathy.

Comment: Hurt the reputation for what?  SEO? Users finding old broken links?

Comment: It is at the very least a security leak to keep old sub-domain references out there. Hackers love them! They can be doorways into the internal network infrastructure. If the sub-domains are no longer needed, then definitely remove them.

Comment: The known attack (which should be an even bigger incentive to clean things than the reputation) is if you have records pointing to hosts at shared or cloud providers external to the enterprise. If suddenly those hosts become available (end of campaign, etc.) and someone gets them then it means an attacker has basically control of resources under one of your name. The problem is the same of course if records are still resolving correctly but forgotten which globally more means that you need to keep close track of all external resources you use, specially on shared platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about SEO because of that don't depends in any sense of DNS records.

But the answer is no, you will not have a negative score for having long time Cname records.

About the mail server score, the question is more about if it is sending mail and what type of mail.

Email deliverability depends on DKIM, SPF, and Spam score, again, rather than DNS records.

Feel free to modify DNS records and try to not break anything in the process because the only thing that DNS can affect in your case will be connectivity or reachability.